# DS18B20 temperature sensor not found in folder

Tags: raspbian, gpio, hardware

I've bought the camjam edukit 2 for my pi which includes the DS18B20 temperature sensor. However, after going over the instructions 20 times, rebuilding it a same amount and searching online, I still haven't managed to get it to show up in the list of devices. This folder remains empty.

I have added the line in boot/config.txt with no success.

The wiring:
[image]

I'm beginning to think the sensor is broken. If anyone has an idea about what I'm doing wrong, I'd be extremely happy to find out!

Running a pi 2 with raspbian

**Updated with answers to the questions in comment**
I plan on using it on a project as well :-)

I added this line to the config file followed by a reboot.

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

Then I tried with this one:

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=4
```

Neither did the trick. The folder that remains empty is this one, added the code before it as well to be complete:

```
sudo modprobe w1-gpio 
sudo modprobe w1-therm 
cd /sys/bus/w1/devices 
ls
```

Comment: It could be faulty? Maybe better ask this question to the people who made the kit and instructions? Or the place you got the kit from?

Comment: The wiring looks okay.  What line have you added to /boot/config.txt?  What folder remains empty?

Comment: And I was planning to use this on a project. *sigh*. Try to follow this and report back what happens: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/hardware

Comment: Could you confirm you have a reasonably recent kernel (uname -a).  Leave dtoverlay=w1-gpio in /boot/config.txt and reboot.  Are the two w1 modules autoloaded (lsmod | grep w1)?

Comment: Did a quick check of my kernel, this was the response:    Linux raspberrypi 4.1.7v7-aufs #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Sep 16 13:19:27 CEST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and I have also already tried to solve it by adding the lines to /boot/config.txt...
I tried serveral different sensors as well as another pi but neither worked...
Did you somehow manage to solve this problem?